# Using iptables to filter traffic on android Wi-Fi hotpots

Tags: networking, android, iptables

I was able to share the Internet by using a hotspot on my android smartphone device, I set up the connection:

[Wi-Fi Hotspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ie7Q.png)

I want to block the traffic that comes from the devices that are connected to the Wi-Fi hotspot. For example, I want to block youtube.com, what should I do by using iptables?
I've tried this on the local network:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

It is working for the local network but not working for the device that is connected to the Wi-Fi hotspot, I also have tried this:
(wlan1 is the hotspot interface of my android device)

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan1 -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

there was no luck, any help would be appreciated, I have been trying to find a way for days.